# Image not loading in Windows Phone - AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have created a test project just for the case. I have one Image control in my .xaml like that:

```
<Image x:Name="img" />
```

I have tested the project with 6 pics, and all of them from the same web Site. Size of images which are shown is approximately 50 - 90 KB. And the image which isn't showing is 294 KB.

And I am setting the source of image like that:

```
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageURI));
```

What could be a problem? 
Thanks.

**UPDATE1:**

Also, I have ckecked ImageFailed event. It is throwing **AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR** exception.

**UPDATE2:**

Here is the source of image which is not showing:
(deleted)

Comment: Why not try asynchronously loading the image? You'll have to install the BCL Async library, which is available in Nuget. There is a guide for it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/04/07/image-tips-for-windows-phone-7.aspx).

Comment: Mind you, the rendering limit is 2000x2000 pixels. So it's probably not your filesize that's the problem!

Comment: @NateDiamond Thanks for the guide. But, the BCL Async Library is noy used in this guide.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen So, what could be a problem? I can gave the source of image , if you want.

Comment: I think you indeed need to provide a sample image source for us to provide any assistance here.

Comment: Do not edit a solution into the question. Post a self-answer and if it's the best, accept it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman :)) ok. I dont want to unmark your answer. Because, it was the real answer. I will delete my edit. ANd that is why you downvoted my question??

Comment: I didn't post an answer. But still: post an answer yourself.

Comment: @HenkHolterman :)) Oh, sorry. I didn't look your name and I thought taht it was the man who had answered the question. :) Sorry. Ok, i will add it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [image in question](http://img.bolumsonucanavari.com/images/videoreview/5878_600x338.jpg) have hot-link protection on.

That is most likely the culprit preventing you from being able to download it. And given the hotlink protection, I'd guess you don't have the necessary rights to use it in a application either.

If you wish to work around this, use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.HttpWebRequest.aspx) class and set the [HttpWebRequest.Referer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer.aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how did you know that the image have protection on?

Comment: Clicking on the link gets a HTTP 403 - Forbidden error code. The reason you don't see it, is that if you paste the link into your browser, you skip the hotlink protection.

Comment: So, I can use these classes to bypass the protection?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do so. But again, I would like to highlight that it's not legal to use 3rd party content in a application without written permission.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am tring to develop a simple application for them because they have not any for Windows Phone. And i will explain them the situation. If they will not give the permission, i won't use it. Thanks very much for helping.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [@Claus Jørgensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95309/claus-jorgensen), I have learned that some web sites can use hot-link protection to prevent other websites from directly linking to files and pictures on your website.
So I create an AttachedProperty for binding the source of Image to URI and download it asynchronously.

Here is .xaml:

```
<Image AttachedProperties:ImageProperties.SourceWithCustomReferer="{Binding Image, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

And AttachedProperty:

```
public static class ImageProperties
{
    #region SourceWithCustomReferer Property
    public static Dictionary<Uri, BitmapImage> imageCache = new Dictionary<Uri, BitmapImage>();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceWithCustomRefererProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "SourceWithCustomReferer",
            typeof(Uri),
            typeof(ImageProperties),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnSourceWithCustomRefererChanged));

    private static void OnSourceWithCustomRefererChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var image = (Image)o;
        var uri = (Uri)e.NewValue;

        if (DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
        {
            // for the design surface we just load the image straight up
            image.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
        }
        else
        {
            if (imageCache.ContainsKey(uri))
            {
                image.Source = imageCache[uri];
                return;
            }

            image.Source = null;

            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Headers["Referer"] = "http://www.WEBSITE.com"; // or your custom referer string here
            request.BeginGetResponse((result) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Stream imageStream = request.EndGetResponse(result).GetResponseStream();
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                        bitmapImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
                        bitmapImage.SetSource(imageStream);
                        image.Source = bitmapImage;
                        imageCache.Add(uri, bitmapImage);
                    });
                }
                catch (WebException)
                {
                    // add error handling
                }
            } , null);
        }
    }

    public static Uri GetSourceWithCustomReferer(Image image)
    {
        if (image == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Image");
        }
        return (Uri)image.GetValue(SourceWithCustomRefererProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSourceWithCustomReferer(Image image, Uri value)
    {
        if (image == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Image");
        }
        image.SetValue(SourceWithCustomRefererProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion
}
```